# Split vals depending on condition

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I need to split invoice.number like if there is white-space Serial is first part and Number is second. But also if there is no whitespace then Serial stays blank and Number will be all invoice.number. how can i do it? 
i need to create some IF statement in my for loop ?

**Update**

for Exmaple invoice.number is AA 555 so Serial will be AA and number will be 555 , but if invoice.number is AA555 Serial will be "" and Number will be AA555. But we don't know what exact invoice.number will be

```
for line in invoice.invoice_line_ids:
     vals = {
            'Serial': invoice.number or '',
            'Number':invoice.number or '',
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becase the values is a dictionary, so you can use it very sample,

```
def parse(number):
    resultList = []
    resultDirt = dict()
    tempList = number.split(" ")
    if len(tempList) > 1:
        resultDirt['Serial'] = tempList[0]
        resultDirt['Number'] = tempList[1]
    else:
        resultDirt['Serial'] = ""
        resultDirt['Number'] = tempList[0]

    resultList.append(resultDirt)
    print(resultList)
    return resultList

parse("1321321 jkhhkhk")
parse("13215465465")
```

The output is,

```
[{'Number': 'jkhhkhk', 'Serial': '1321321'}]
[{'Number': '13215465465', 'Serial': ''}]
```

Comment: invoice number will be already set.. so if there is invoice.number with whitespace we split it to Serial and Number if it without whitespace Serial stays blank and all invoice.number will be "Number"

Comment: the problem we don't know.. what invoice.number will be. i updated my question